# How to remove duplicates from an Arraylist by latest date

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

I need to remove duplicates based on the latest date.

```
class Stat {

    private String country;
    private String state;
    private String fullname;
    Date indepdate;

    public Stat(String country,String state,String fullname,int indepdate){
        this.country=country;
        this.state=state;
        this.fullname=fullname;
        this.indepdate=indepdate;
    }

   //also getters and setters

    public String toString() {
         return "("+country+","+state+","+fullname+","+indepdate+")";
    } 
}
```

---

```
ArrayList<Stat> stats  =new  ArrayList();

Stats.add(new Stat("USA", "Florida", "John Jones", 5/1/2020));
Stats.add(new Stat("USA", "Florida", "Jeff Cane", 4/1/2016));
Stats.add(new Stat("USA", "California", "Lisa Smith", 3/1/2000));
Stats.add(new Stat("Germany", "Florida", "Tom Joseph", 5/1/2019));
Stats.add(new Stat("Germany", "Florida", "Chris Richard", 5/1/2018));
Stats.add(new Stat("Germany", "California", "Nancy Diaz", 4/3/2015));
```

I need to remove duplicate countries and only keep countries with the latest date.

The list should look like this:

```
USA, florida, John James, 5/1/2020
Germany,Florida,Tom Joseph, 5/1/2019
```

So far I have the following:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Stat>> 
           groupByCountryAndCity = stats.
             stream().
               collect(
                    Collectors.
                        groupingBy(
                            Stat::getCountry,
                            Collectors.
                                groupingBy(
                                     Stat::getIndepdate     
                                          )
                                   )
                     );
```

Comment: And the problem is... ?

Comment: That's not how you create a date.

Comment: As it was pointed out, your `Date` is not initialized properly, try looking here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LocalDate` for `indepdate` field.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Stat {

    private String country;
    private String state;
    private String fullname;
    private LocalDate indepdate;

    // ...
}
```

Then use the `LocalDate.of()` method: `LocalDate.of(2020, 5, 1)`

Try this:

```
List<Stat> output = stats.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Stat::getCountry, Function.identity(),
                BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Stat::getIndepdate)),
                () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(String::toString).reversed())))
        .values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output:

```
[(USA,Florida,John Jones,2020-05-01), (Germany,Florida,Tom Joseph,2019-05-01)]
```

Comment: Good answer. I like [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65342285/5221149) better, of course, but either way works. +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks, I can't race with you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the following `Collectors` methods:

- [`groupingBy(Function<> classifier, Collector<> downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)
- [`collectingAndThen(Collector<> downstream, Function<> finisher)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-)
- [`maxBy(Comparator<> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#maxBy-java.util.Comparator-)

```java
List<Stat> stats = Arrays.asList(
        new Stat("USA", "Florida", "John Jones", "5/1/2020"),
        new Stat("USA", "Florida", "Jeff Cane", "4/1/2016"),
        new Stat("USA", "California", "Lisa Smith", "3/1/2000"),
        new Stat("Germany", "Florida", "Tom Joseph", "5/1/2019"),
        new Stat("Germany", "Florida", "Chris Richard", "5/1/2018"),
        new Stat("Germany", "California", "Nancy Diaz", "4/3/2015") );

Map<String, Stat> result = stats.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Stat::getCountry,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Stat::getIndepdate)),
                        Optional::get)));

result.values().forEach(System.out::println);
```

```java
class Stat {
    private final String country;
    private final String state;
    private final String fullname;
    private final LocalDate indepdate;

    public Stat(String country, String state, String fullname, String indepdate){
        this.country = country;
        this.state = state;
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.indepdate = LocalDate.parse(indepdate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u"));
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return this.state;
    }
    public String getFullname() {
        return this.fullname;
    }
    public LocalDate getIndepdate() {
        return this.indepdate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "("+country+","+state+","+fullname+","+indepdate+")";
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
(USA,Florida,John Jones,2020-05-01)
(Germany,Florida,Tom Joseph,2019-05-01)
```

Comment: @NennaAnya Your question is using Java Streams, so this answer is using Java Streams. and since Streams were added in Java 8, you're right, it won't work i Java 7.

Answer (score -2):

yu might use the reducing of streams which Collectors provides. Sth. lik this:

```
stats.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Stat::getCountry,reducing(Comparator.comparing(Stat::getIndepDate))));
```

Comment: What is `reducing()`?

Comment: from the javadoc of java.util.stream.Collectors: 
     * Returns a {@code Collector} which performs a reduction of its
     * input elements under a specified {@code BinaryOperator}.

Comment: Can't see that in the answer. Why did you not leave the `Collectors.` on that one, like you did for the others. With snippets of code like this, it's bad to use static imports, since it hides relevant information. --- Anyway, [`reducing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) doesn't take a `Comparator`, so *that code doesn't work*.

Comment: I have the balls, which is why I already gave a reason (incomplete answer, using undefined method). I now gave another, and even better, reason (code doesn't work, doesn't compile).

Comment: ok, first: I wrote "yu might use the reducing of streams which Collectors provides." which should make it possible to see in the answer, where it comes from. second: your kind of right - my code was not tested. But I guess it is not that hard to look into the javadoc and see, that one might wrap this into BinaryOperator.maxBy. And an answer should help, not do the work of the one who asks.